# Direct sum of $T^n$

Tags: linear-algebra

**Question**
Let $T:V\to V , dimV=n , \Bbb F= \Bbb C$ a linear map
Prove that $KerT^n \oplus ImT^n=V$

**Thoughts**
We tried using the rank nullity theorem but got stuck, as we don't know what is $dim(ImT+KerT)$

Comment: Does [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/669442) help?